# JavaScript prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

I'm trying to inherit the methods of one object into another.

I've got the base object , which is implemented using the *Revealing Module Pattern*.

```
Page = function(url) {
    ...
    return { something: something_I_defined_above }
    ...
}
```

The other object where Page should inherit from is defined as a singleton.
In the actual file Page is defined before Link is.

```
Link = function() {
   this.add = function() {}

   var instance = this;

   Link = function() { return instance; }
}
```

Next I want Page to inherit from Link.

```
Page.prototype = new Link();
```

When testing this code I get undefined for the p function:

```
var p = new Page();
// The following line return undefined.
p.add;
```

Answer (score 3):

You never really instantiate a `Page` object. All you do is returning a plain object literal when you call

```
Page = function(url) {
    ...
    return { something: something_I_defined_above }
    ...
}

var p = new Page();
```

This literal does not inherit from `Page.prototype`. There are some ways to solve this, mostly depending on how you want to structure your application.

For example, instead of letting `Page` inherit from `Link` (does this even make sense?) you can return an object that inherits from `Link`:

```
Page = function(url) {
    ...
    var Constr = function(){};
    Constr.prototype = new Link();
    var instance = new Constr();
    instance.something = something_I_defined_above;

    return instance;
    ...
}

var p = new Page();
```

I'm actually unsure what would be the best approach here. It really depends on what you want. My suggestion would to not make it too complicated.

Comment: The LInk object has similar problems.  First time he calls it, it returns undefined.

Comment: @Matt: Yes but it is called with `new`, so it will return `this` at the first call and `instance` on any subsequent call (with or without `new`).

Comment: I had my suspicions that the problem would be with the revealing module pattern. I can see why it doesn't work as I expected it to.

Comment: @Felix I had no idea that a 'new' call will return 'this' even in the absence of a return value.  Intriguing.

Comment: @Matt: Now you know :) If you call a function with `new`, `this` will refer to a new object that inherits from the functions prototype. If no *object* is *explicitly* returned by the function, `this` is returned *implicitly*. You can try to return a number or string and you will see that you get `this` nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks!
I had my suspicions that the problem would be with the revealing module pattern. I can see that the constructor of the Page object returns just an other object literal which doesn't inherit from Page.prototype.
I moved away from the revealing module pattern so I can still use Page.prototype = new Link();

Comment: @Jonas: Yes that is another way. Although you have to ask yourself, does it make sense that `Link` is a singleton and that `Page` inherits from `Link`? If both these terms are used in the common sense, then I would say that `Page` *contains* a `Link`. Also note that any changes you make to `Page.prototype` after you assigned `new Link()` to it, will also change the `Link` instance.